# Access values created by QScriptEngine on heap?

Tags: c++, qt, qtscript

### [Question]

Suppose we feed [`QScriptEngine`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html) with the following script:

```
var foo = 1;
var bar = 2;
foo + bar
```

by [`QScriptEngine::evaluate()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#evaluate), we'll get a [`QScriptValue`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptvalue.html) returned which can be translated back into `int` equal to 3.

On the other hand, if we feed [`QScriptEngine`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html) with the script:

```
var foo = 1;
var bar = 2;
```

Then how can we access the values of `foo` and `bar` created by the script on heap?

### [Example]

[image]

Take MATLAB (Python IDLE is the same) as an example. I can read the script file and the variables created by script will still be available to command prompt.

I am thinking about doing the same thing in Qt:

1. Read the script file to `QString`
2. Call `QScriptEngine::evaluate()` to evaluate the `QString`

But I can't figure out how to get those `var` created by the script.

P.S. The script could be very complicated and not just contend variables only, I just try to make the question simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If variables are global then they're accessible in the [global object](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#globalObject) (through `globalObject()` method). From documentation:

> ...Non-local variables in script code will be created as properties of the Global Object, as well as local variables in global code.

In short you have to obtain global object and then [iterate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptvalueiterator.html) through its properties to read their values with [property()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptvalue.html#property) method (please note that you'll have to only variables from your script):

```
QScriptValueIterator it(engine.globalObject());
 while (it.hasNext()) {
     it.next();
     qDebug() << it.name() << ": " << it.value().toString();
 }
```

Comment: Hmm...Sorry I think I didn't make my question clear enough. The script is quite complicated and it's not variables only. I'm gonna edit my question and exemplify it.

Comment: If it's not _variables only_ what you would include? All objects in global scope will be there (exactly as in MATLAB). I guess you know so I repeat only for clarity: if you call evaluate() multiple times then engine status is preserved between calls (then variables can be reused and you can show them MATLAB style iterating global object).

Comment: Thank you Adriano. You are right, everything is just right where they should be.